# How to configure Maven project to not expect resources directory in Eclipse

Tags: maven, resources, m2eclipse, pom.xml

I do not have any resources for my Maven project so I want to stop Maven expecting these directories and so remove these Java Build Path Problems in Eclipse,

```
Project 'XXX' is missing required source folder: 't-services/src/test/resources'
Project 'XXX' is missing required source folder: 'tlib/src/main/resources'
```

How do I configure pom.xml to achieve this?

Comment: I don't get this issues in Eclipse Indigo with m2e when importing a simple maven project without `resources` folders.  Can you give more details about the environment (Eclipse version, etc) and how you have imported this project in Eclipse?

Answer (score 7):

A quite old thread, but I just faced the similar errors in Eclipse, after having deleted the src/main/java + resources and src/test/java + resources from Eclipse directly, as my project is only containing a pom file (packaging=pom).

To properly remove the errors, I just right-clicked on the project > Properties > Java Build Path > 'Source' tab, and there I removed the obsoletes entries. In the end, it modified the .classpath file of the project.

Comment: This will only resolve the problem temporarily. If you're using m2e, it will come back the next time you update the project from the pom.

Answer (score 0):

Janek, I saw similar with m2e <= 1.0 but it seems to be fixed with m2e 1.1.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to clear up a similar problem. I removed the projects from Eclipse; deleted all of the .project, .classpath, and .settings files and directories from the file system; imported the project into Eclipse again. The problem went away.

Answer (score -2):

you have to simply remove those folders from your project after that there shouldn't be any problem...But the message gives me the impression that those folders have been configured wrong...

Comment: The folders do not exist which is correct. I want to configure the project to remove the warnings about the resource folders being missing because I want these folders to be missing.

Comment: You didn't read the second part of my answer. The configuration of your project (pom) seemed to be wrong, but I can't say anything about that, cause i have no pom here....